# What is the largest image that can be read in OpenCV?

Tags: image, opencv, gdal

I have some *very* large GeoTiff mosaics (50,000 x 50,000 cells with as many as 4 bands). OpenCV returns `None` when using `imread` for these images, but successfully reads smaller images (2,880 x 3,840). Since `imread` works with cropped versions of the same large mosaics, it appears to be an issue with the image size, and not the images themselves. I have two questions:

- What is the largest image that `imread` can deal with?
- `is there a way to read a subset/ROI of an image in OpenCV (similar to band.ReadAsArray(xoff, yoff, xcount, ycount)` in GDAL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum size is bounded by the maximum value of `size_t`. You can see is OpenCV function [setSize](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/56c89e0a980d39d8ee41752e896f08a267396873/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp#L276) that the size depends on:

- **element size**: the size of the underlying type multiplied by the number of channels. E.g. a `Mat4b` (or `Mat` of type `CV_8UC4`) is `8*4 = 32`
- **number of elements** : the number of elements in the matrix. For a 2D matrix is simply `rows * cols`.

For 32 bit builds, then the total size of the matrix: `sizeof(type) * channels * rows * cols` should be less than `2^32 = 4294967296`.

In your case, assuming a matrix of `uchar` with 4 channels, the size will be: `8 * 4 * 50000 * 50000 = 80000000000 > 4294967296`, and that's too big.

You can have bigger images with a 64 bit build.

---

No, OpenCV doesn't provide a function to read from disk only a ROI of an image. You need to rely on other libraries to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on where to start looking. To be frank, I thought I was using 64-bit libraries throughout.  Since I am using Anaconda to set up a consistent toolchain across 5 different platforms, I have little control over the provided packages.  I will look more deeply into the 32/64-bit status.

Comment: I was able to get the image to read using "img = bnd.ReadAsArray(1024, 2048, 1024, 1024)", but I thought there might be a way to do it all from OpenCV and keep the code cleaner.  Thank you for the confirmation of no ROI features in OpenCV.